# Why Swift optional become zero?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

This is my custom Demo class:

```
class Demo: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var id: Int?

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.id = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey("ID")
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        if let id = self.id{
            aCoder.encodeInteger(id, forKey: "ID")
        }

    }
}
```

Save I have create a object and save into NSUserDefaults like this:

```
let demo = Demo()
let archiveData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(demo)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(archiveData, forKey: "ff")
```

Debug result shows that it works good

[image]

Now I have picked the object from NSUserDefaults like this:

```
let retainData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("ff") as! NSData
let retainDemo = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(retainData) as! Demo
```

Now after debugging I have found:

[image]

Now check the difference between the two result. Previous one id value nil after pick the object from then the id value become zero. I have not made any change of the object. Just save into NSUserdefaults and pick reversely. What the reason behind this? How do I overcome the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that `decodeIntegerForKey` does not return an optional Int. It returns an Int. So if ID is not present then it returns 0 which is usually the default value of a Int variable. You can fix this by checking the decoder has the ID object.

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    if aDecoder.containsValueForKey("ID") {
        self.id = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey("ID")
    }
}
```